# Prove that $\leq_p\subseteq\mathbb N^\infty\times\mathbb N^\infty$ is transitive

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory

I am learning a programming learning and there while learning semantics I came across this question.

> Let $\mathbb N^\infty$ be the set of all infinite sequences of natural numbers (e.g., $[0,0,2,2,4,4,\dotsc]\in\mathbb N^\infty$) and let $\leq_p\subseteq\mathbb N^\infty\times\mathbb N^\infty$ be the relation that compares infinite sequences of natural numbers by their *prefix sums*. The $n$th prefix sum $p_n(s)$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$ of a sequence $s\in\mathbb N^\infty$ is the sum of the first $n$ elements of $s$. We have $s\leq_p s'$  if and only if $s = s'$ or there is an $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $p_n(s)<p_n(s')$ and $p_m(s) = p_m(s')$ for all $m\in \{0,\dotsc, n-1\}$.
>
> 1. Prove that $\leq_p$ is transitive.
> 2. Give an example for an infinite chain in $(\mathbb N^\infty, \leq_p)$.

[Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUJky.png)

It will be great, if someone explain me how to prove this. Thank you.

Comment: This seems to be a pure mathematics question with not apparent relation to CS. Migrating.

Comment: This just a tedious exercise in verifying definitions. For the second part, just take the constant $0$ sequence, and start modifying it.

Comment: @AsafKaragilaHi Asaf, can you please explain a bit, why should i start with  0? is [0,0,1,1,2,2..]  correct?

Comment: @nobe you can start wherever you want (all 0s is just a natural starting point). Have you actually tried modifying any sequences by hand and comparing them? If you did, at least problem 2 should be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** This is equivalent to plain old lexicographical ordering.

Comment: hi, do you have any source where i can learn these, its been a so long time i am struggling with these types of questions and I have a exam on tuesday. so i have to prepare for it. kindly please help me if you can. thank you.

Comment: As Asaf Karagila said, there isn't much to learn. Do you know how transitivity is defined? All you need to do is to check that definition. My answer is only useful in that, when you realize it's a lexicographical ordering, the two properties should be obvious.